# NLP - Fetch words which is not part of English grammar

Tags: nlp, nltk, text-mining

I have a requirement where I have to read a text and extract only the SQL Table Names and Column names.

Eg statement: "Direct move by joining the Table_A with Table_B on Column_1

In the above example I have to read only the table name and column name. Similarly I have even complex and large statements, from which I have to extract table and columns names.

I have tried using the POS tagging from NLTK package. But I am not sure if the POS tagging is a valid approach in this requirement, because the words I am trying to extract is not an exact English grammar word.

Any idea on how I can approach this? Please throw some light.

Comment: Do table/column names have some unified format? Like containing an underscore? Maybe regular expressions would help?

Comment: @AnastasiiaIurshina Yes it contains underscore in all table and column names. Regex crossed my mind earlier. Do you think it might work for larger statements too? At times my statement is more than 10 lines.